# How to shorten this java code?

Tags: java, android

I am making a timetable app for android and loading a `JSON` file with all the data to be parsed in a table of `TextView`s.

It's a lot of copy paste work. Now I'm using a lot of the same code.
Is it possible to shorten this code? If so, how ?

```
        resetrooster();             
    String jsonStr = jsonStr(); 

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

        //JSON Array node
        removed_classes = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_REMOVED_CLASSES);
        classes = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CLASSES);
        new_classes = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_NEW_CLASSES);


        //Looping through all lessons
        for (int i = 0; i < classes.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = classes.getJSONObject(i);

            String day = c.getString(TAG_DAY);
            String room = c.getString(TAG_ROOM);
            String hour = c.getString(TAG_HOUR);
            String classs = c.getString(TAG_CLASSS);
            String teacher = c.getString(TAG_TEACHER);

            //Fill in the right lessons for the right day
            if (theday == 1){
                if (day.contains("1")){
                    if (hour.contains("1") && !hour.contains("10") && !hour.contains("11") && !hour.contains("12") && !hour.contains("13") ){
                        uur1.setText(hour); doc1.setText(teacher); vak1.setText(classs); lok1.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("2")&& !hour.contains("12")){
                            uur2.setText(hour); doc2.setText(teacher); vak2.setText(classs); lok2.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("3")&& !hour.contains("13")){
                            uur3.setText(hour); doc3.setText(teacher); vak3.setText(classs); lok3.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("4")){
                            uur4.setText(hour); doc4.setText(teacher); vak4.setText(classs); lok4.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("5")){
                            uur5.setText(hour); doc5.setText(teacher); vak5.setText(classs); lok5.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("6")){
                            uur6.setText(hour); doc6.setText(teacher); vak6.setText(classs); lok6.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("7")){
                            uur7.setText(hour); doc7.setText(teacher); vak7.setText(classs); lok7.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("8")){
                            uur8.setText(hour); doc8.setText(teacher); vak8.setText(classs); lok8.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("9")){
                            uur9.setText(hour); doc9.setText(teacher); vak9.setText(classs); lok9.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("10")){
                            uur10.setText(hour); doc10.setText(teacher); vak10.setText(classs); lok10.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("11")){
                            uur11.setText(hour); doc11.setText(teacher); vak11.setText(classs); lok11.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("12")){
                            uur12.setText(hour); doc12.setText(teacher); vak12.setText(classs); lok12.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("13")){
                            uur13.setText(hour); doc13.setText(teacher); vak13.setText(classs); lok13.setText(room);}

                    }}
            else if (theday == 2){
                if (day.contains("2")){
                        if (hour.contains("1") && !hour.contains("10") && !hour.contains("11") && !hour.contains("12") && !hour.contains("13") ){
                            uur1.setText(hour); doc1.setText(teacher); vak1.setText(classs); lok1.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("2")&& !hour.contains("12")){
                            uur2.setText(hour); doc2.setText(teacher); vak2.setText(classs); lok2.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("3")&& !hour.contains("13")){
                            uur3.setText(hour); doc3.setText(teacher); vak3.setText(classs); lok3.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("4")){
                            uur4.setText(hour); doc4.setText(teacher); vak4.setText(classs); lok4.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("5")){
                            uur5.setText(hour); doc5.setText(teacher); vak5.setText(classs); lok5.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("6")){
                            uur6.setText(hour); doc6.setText(teacher); vak6.setText(classs); lok6.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("7")){
                            uur7.setText(hour); doc7.setText(teacher); vak7.setText(classs); lok7.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("8")){
                            uur8.setText(hour); doc8.setText(teacher); vak8.setText(classs); lok8.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("9")){
                            uur9.setText(hour); doc9.setText(teacher); vak9.setText(classs); lok9.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("10")){
                            uur10.setText(hour); doc10.setText(teacher); vak10.setText(classs); lok10.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("11")){
                            uur11.setText(hour); doc11.setText(teacher); vak11.setText(classs); lok11.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("12")){
                            uur12.setText(hour); doc12.setText(teacher); vak12.setText(classs); lok12.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("13")){
                            uur13.setText(hour); doc13.setText(teacher); vak13.setText(classs); lok13.setText(room);}
                    }}
            else if (theday == 3){
                if (day.contains("3")){
                    if (hour.contains("1") && !hour.contains("10") && !hour.contains("11") && !hour.contains("12") && !hour.contains("13") ){
                        uur1.setText(hour); doc1.setText(teacher); vak1.setText(classs); lok1.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("2")&& !hour.contains("12")){
                            uur2.setText(hour); doc2.setText(teacher); vak2.setText(classs); lok2.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("3")&& !hour.contains("13")){
                            uur3.setText(hour); doc3.setText(teacher); vak3.setText(classs); lok3.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("4")){
                            uur4.setText(hour); doc4.setText(teacher); vak4.setText(classs); lok4.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("5")){
                            uur5.setText(hour); doc5.setText(teacher); vak5.setText(classs); lok5.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("6")){
                            uur6.setText(hour); doc6.setText(teacher); vak6.setText(classs); lok6.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("7")){
                            uur7.setText(hour); doc7.setText(teacher); vak7.setText(classs); lok7.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("8")){
                            uur8.setText(hour); doc8.setText(teacher); vak8.setText(classs); lok8.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("9")){
                            uur9.setText(hour); doc9.setText(teacher); vak9.setText(classs); lok9.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("10")){
                            uur10.setText(hour); doc10.setText(teacher); vak10.setText(classs); lok10.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("11")){
                            uur11.setText(hour); doc11.setText(teacher); vak11.setText(classs); lok11.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("12")){
                            uur12.setText(hour); doc12.setText(teacher); vak12.setText(classs); lok12.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("13")){
                            uur13.setText(hour); doc13.setText(teacher); vak13.setText(classs); lok13.setText(room);}
                    }}
            else if (theday == 4){
                if (day.contains("4")){
                    if (hour.contains("1") && !hour.contains("10") && !hour.contains("11") && !hour.contains("12") && !hour.contains("13") ){
                        uur1.setText(hour); doc1.setText(teacher); vak1.setText(classs); lok1.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("2")&& !hour.contains("12")){
                            uur2.setText(hour); doc2.setText(teacher); vak2.setText(classs); lok2.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("3")&& !hour.contains("13")){
                            uur3.setText(hour); doc3.setText(teacher); vak3.setText(classs); lok3.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("4")){
                            uur4.setText(hour); doc4.setText(teacher); vak4.setText(classs); lok4.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("5")){
                            uur5.setText(hour); doc5.setText(teacher); vak5.setText(classs); lok5.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("6")){
                            uur6.setText(hour); doc6.setText(teacher); vak6.setText(classs); lok6.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("7")){
                            uur7.setText(hour); doc7.setText(teacher); vak7.setText(classs); lok7.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("8")){
                            uur8.setText(hour); doc8.setText(teacher); vak8.setText(classs); lok8.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("9")){
                            uur9.setText(hour); doc9.setText(teacher); vak9.setText(classs); lok9.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("10")){
                            uur10.setText(hour); doc10.setText(teacher); vak10.setText(classs); lok10.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("11")){
                            uur11.setText(hour); doc11.setText(teacher); vak11.setText(classs); lok11.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("12")){
                            uur12.setText(hour); doc12.setText(teacher); vak12.setText(classs); lok12.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("13")){
                            uur13.setText(hour); doc13.setText(teacher); vak13.setText(classs); lok13.setText(room);}
                    }}
            else if (theday == 5){
                if (day.contains("5")){
                    if (hour.contains("1") && !hour.contains("10") && !hour.contains("11") && !hour.contains("12") && !hour.contains("13") ){
                        uur1.setText(hour); doc1.setText(teacher); vak1.setText(classs); lok1.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("2")&& !hour.contains("12")){
                            uur2.setText(hour); doc2.setText(teacher); vak2.setText(classs); lok2.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("3")&& !hour.contains("13")){
                            uur3.setText(hour); doc3.setText(teacher); vak3.setText(classs); lok3.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("4")){
                            uur4.setText(hour); doc4.setText(teacher); vak4.setText(classs); lok4.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("5")){
                            uur5.setText(hour); doc5.setText(teacher); vak5.setText(classs); lok5.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("6")){
                            uur6.setText(hour); doc6.setText(teacher); vak6.setText(classs); lok6.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("7")){
                            uur7.setText(hour); doc7.setText(teacher); vak7.setText(classs); lok7.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("8")){
                            uur8.setText(hour); doc8.setText(teacher); vak8.setText(classs); lok8.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("9")){
                            uur9.setText(hour); doc9.setText(teacher); vak9.setText(classs); lok9.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("10")){
                            uur10.setText(hour); doc10.setText(teacher); vak10.setText(classs); lok10.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("11")){
                            uur11.setText(hour); doc11.setText(teacher); vak11.setText(classs); lok11.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("12")){
                            uur12.setText(hour); doc12.setText(teacher); vak12.setText(classs); lok12.setText(room);}
                        if (hour.contains("13")){
                            uur13.setText(hour); doc13.setText(teacher); vak13.setText(classs); lok13.setText(room);}
                    }}

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `How to shorten this javascript code?` ????????javascript?????? `Is it possible to shorten this code?` yes, it is possible

Comment: This doesn't look like javascript.  Is this java?

Comment: This is what we mean by spaghetti code. Is this is production???(shocked)

Comment: Android is written in java.

Comment: Sorry, I ment java. autocomplete fail... :(

Comment: HashMaps may be useful; coupling an hour to its corresponding uur, doc, vak and lok (please use better variable names). Even better put all 4 in a single object

Answer (score 1):

I would start by creating a class "Session" which encapsulates the uurN, docN, vakN, and lokN fields as instance variables (also name those better). Then add a fill method to accept these four fields and fill out the instance variables.

```
public class Session {
    private final TextView hour;
    private final TextView teacher;
    private final TextView subject;
    private final TextView room;

    public Session(TextView hourTextView, TextView teacherTextView, TextView subjectTextView, TextView roomTextView) {
        this.hourTextView = hourTextView;
        this.teacherTextView = teacherTextView;
        this.subjectTextView = subjectTextView;
        this.roomTextView = roomTextView;
    }

    public void fill(String hour, String teacher, String subject, String room) {
        hourTextView.setText(hour);
        teacherTextView.setText(teacher);
        subjectTextView.setText(subject);
        roomTextView.setText(room);
    }
}
```

Then I would create a HashMap lets call it sessions, mapping the hour to the session object.

```
HashMap<Byte, Session> sessions = new HashMap<Byte, Session>();
sessions.add(1, new Session(uur1, doc1, vak1, lok1));
sessions.add(2, new Session(uur2, doc2, vak2, lok2)); //etc
```

Then you can just do something like:

```
sessions.get(hour).fill(hour, teacher, classs, room);
```

Also just use someString.equals("1") if you need to test equality rather than someString.contains("1") and then need to exclude all the other possibilities.